# Trying to output php -> md5 -> html but the file is empty

Tags: php, html, md5, invoices

I'm currently using a open source solution for my invoices called MyClientBase and everything is working really well.

Normally when I generate an invoice to a client, I can either do it as a PDF or e-mail (or HTML). When generating the HTML-invoice the link to it is secure (only logged in users can view the invoice) so I'm trying to make publicly viewable invoices that generates a md5-html that we can send in the e-mails.

Right now it's working by generating a md5-html file in the right folder and everything is great, except that the html-file is empty. I've set the CHMOD to 777 on the folder and tried several solutions but nothing really works. Instead it generates two invoices (duplicates) on the same page and leaves the html-file empty. So I think some skilled php/html-guy might figure this one out.

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
function generate_html() {

$invoice_id = uri_assoc('invoice_id');

$this->load->library('invoices/lib_output');

$this->load->model('invoices/mdl_invoice_history');

$this->mdl_invoice_history->save($invoice_id, $this->session->userdata('user_id'), $this->lang->line('generated_invoice_html'));

$this->lib_output->html($invoice_id, uri_assoc('invoice_template'));

 /*  ------------------ GENERATE MD5-HTML ---------------------------  */
     $file = md5('my_output_path'.$invoice_id).'.html';

     echo "<a href='my_output_path".$file."'>Link to client invoice</a>";
     $f = fopen('my_invoice_path'.$file, 'w');
     $template = $this->load->view('invoice_templates/default_template');
 fwrite($f, $template);true;    
     /*  ------------------ End generate md5 ---------------------------  */
     }
```

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Can you check the different paths you used. Perhaps, there is a mystake : you use "my_output_path" as HREF URL and FILE PATH.

Comment: So your problem has absolutely nothing to do with invoices, PDF or MD5 , does it?

Comment: Also, is the invoice display when you "echo $template" ; if true, the problem come from file handler or path. Then check the return of "fopen".

Comment: @Akarun: I've checked it several times. The file is generated in the right folder with the right name and the original invoice looks great. It's just the output-file that's empty.

Comment: @Alvaro: Well I get your point, but it's difficult for me to know what's causing this problem. The question is about a md5-generated invoice, I haven't written anything about pdf really.

Comment: i believe $this->load->view does not actually store the html output in the variable $template, or does it? did u try to print $template to make sure it actually has the value you expect it to have, and the duplicate invoices might be just cos the method view() is just printing the invoice again.

Comment: @Akarun when I echo $template nothing really happens. The invoice is generated perfectly in secure URL but echo $template doesn't do any difference. When I replace $template with $invoice_id the md5-generated file outputs only the id of the invoice, otherwise it's empty.

Comment: @AL-Kateb yeah you might be right, I'm not very skilled in this field so I thought that the fwrite would output the template+md5-generated html into the folder = fwrite ($f, $template);

Comment: Try to add : fwrite($f, "test content"); fclose($f); at the end to test de writting of the file.

Comment: @Akarun That works. The md5-generated html-file now outputs "test content". I'm not sure the fclose help. I still got a output with the invoice id when I did fwrite ($f, $invoice_id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it should work, what it does is it fetches the output, and store it in a variable then this variable will be the content of that file it might need some tweaks tell me if you get any errors

```
function generate_html() {

$invoice_id = uri_assoc('invoice_id');

$this->load->library('invoices/lib_output');

$this->load->model('invoices/mdl_invoice_history');

$this->mdl_invoice_history->save($invoice_id, $this->session->userdata('user_id'), $this->lang->line('generated_invoice_html'));

$this->lib_output->html($invoice_id, uri_assoc('invoice_template'));

 /*  ------------------ GENERATE MD5-HTML ---------------------------  */
     $file = md5('my_output_path'.$invoice_id).'.html';

     echo "<a href='my_output_path".$file."'>Link to client invoice</a>";
     $f = fopen('my_invoice_path'.$file, 'w');
     ob_start(); // start output buffer flow
     $old_content = ob_get_contents();
     ob_clean();
     $this->load->view('invoice_templates/default_template');
     $template = ob_get_contents(); // assign buffer contents to variable
     ob_end_clean(); // end buffer and remove buffer contents
     fwrite($f, $template);true;   
     echo $old_content;

     /*  ------------------ End generate md5 ---------------------------  */
     }
```

Comment: Omg you solved it. I really really really appreciate it! Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After "comment discusion", the problem come from the $template that not contain the HTML of your invoice.

The result of 
    $this->load->view('invoice_templates/default_template');
does not contain HTML but, perhaps, only a status code.

I think you can search in this direction.